# Как стабилизировать изображение линий шара sfml c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Решил написать что то типо "светящегося шарика". Идея состоит в том, что из за того, что тонкие линии отрисовываться не совсем корректно, создаётся эффект освещения, ведь те линии что ближе к центру достаточно яркие, а те что дальше от цента достаточно темные. Но эта некорректность иногда бывает слишком большая, что приводит к артефактам. Как это исправить? Вот код

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    srand(5);
    sf::ContextSettings setts;
    setts.antialiasingLevel = 1;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(360, 800), "Convex Circle", sf::Style::Close, setts);

    const int numPoints = 3000;
    float radius = 180.0f; // Радиус окружности
    const float centerX = window.getSize().x / 2.0f;
    const float centerY = window.getSize().y / 2.0f;

    sf::ConvexShape circle;
    circle.setPointCount(numPoints);

    int counter = 0; // Счетчик

    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        srand(rand());
        float ang = i * 2 * M_PI / numPoints;       //угол точки
        float x = centerX + radius * std::cos(ang); // X координата
        float y = centerY + radius * std::sin(ang); // Y координата

        if (i % 2 == 0) // проверяем, является ли точка каждой второй точкой
        {
            float newRadius = radius - 120.0f;       // уменьшаем радиус на 20
            x = centerX + newRadius * std::cos(ang); // пересчитываем X координату с новым радиусом
            y = centerY + newRadius * std::sin(ang); // пересчитываем Y координату с новым радиусом
        }

        circle.setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(x, y));

        counter++;
    }

    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(circle);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот фотография результата
[image: скриншот]

Как вы видите из за некорректности тонких линий, появляется не только эффект освещения, но ещё и артефакты. И ведь это ещё со включенным антиалиасингом. Можно ли как то уменьшить такие артефакты, и оставить эффект освещения?

Comment: Антиалиазинг побольше поставить. Или вообще не рисовать линии, один раз вычислить картинку, и потом ее просто рисовать. Или шейдером рисовать. (И то и другое без линий, просто градиент.)

Comment: да, как вам правильно подсказывают, попробуйте `antialiasingLevel = 8` обычно на всех gpu проходит, если даже не пройдёт sfml обычно уменьшает до ближайшего приемлимого, например до 4

Comment: Если антиалиасинг больше одного, то изображение просто пропадает